# Jira issue view make custom-field read-only

Tags: javascript, jira, jira-plugin

You can edit a custom-fields value in 3 ways.

1. issue creation
2. issue edit by click on edit
3. issue edit by click on the output-field with the pencil

The first 2 are similiar and work fine.

But the third looks different and I don't want people to edit it this way. Is there any option to disable this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable the Inline edit option using JIRA administrative functions.
navigate to jira administrative options in the right corner of the menu bar and go to the "System" option in that menu.

then click on the Edit settings and bottom of the list you can see the option to disable the inline edit.
[image]
**UPDATE**

If you need to disable the inline edit for a particular custom field you can use simple javascript to do that...

Ex: if you need to disable inline edit on assignee field then you can follow these steps.

1.Go to Administration > Issues > Field Configurations

2.Click on Configure link at 'Default Field Configuration'

3.Click on Edit link at 'Assignee'

In the Description field, add the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var removeCTE = setInterval(function() {
var editableElms = AJS.$('#assignee-val')
if (editableElms.length)    {  
    editableElms.removeClass('inactive'); 
    editableElms.removeClass('editable-field'); 
    editableElms.removeAttr('title'); 
    editableElms.find('span.overlay-icon').hide(); 
}},500);
</script>
```

for more information you can follow this [link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAKB/How+to+Disable+Inline+Edit+for+Assignee+Field)

Comment: Is there a way to disable this for just one field instead of doing it for all fields?

Comment: In my case I added the javascript into my field-view (because JIRA may disable HTML-Code in field description like they did with the announcement banner) and wrapped a static <div>-id around my custom-field to disable the edit-option for all instances of this field. Thanks for the solution, JIRA knowledge seems to be rare.